# TYPO3 / TypoScript: How to make a fallback?

Tags: typo3, fallback, typoscript, fallbackvalue

I want to output a string to the rendered HTML by using two fallbacks.

My typoscript is defined at the top level page (root page of my website) and is passed to all pages at lower levels.

Structure:

- Homepage

  - Page at level 1

    - Page at level 2

### Regular output of the file:

The string comes from a TemplaVoila field (Page / Edit / Extended / MyField): **field_copyright_name**

To output it to the desired point in the HTML output a templaVoila mapping exists (Type: Typoscript Object Path), named: **lib.copyright_name**

The following typoscript does the job:

```
lib.hint_copyright_name = COA
lib.hint_copyright_name.10 = TEXT
lib.hint_copyright_name.10 {
    setCurrent.dataWrap = {field:field_copyright_name}
    current = 1
}
```

This works for all pages at all levels where the field (in page properties) is not empty.

### The first fallback:

If the field is empty (in properties of that page, e.g. at level 2) typoscript should get the value from the pages above (at level 1, and if it is empty too, it should get it from homepage). No clue how to do it. Can you help?

### The second fallback

If the first fallback still returns an empty string (because the field was empty at all levels) it should do a fallback to a default value "Copyright by me".

To enable this fallback without "first fallback" is easy:

```
switchdefault_copyright_name = TEXT
switchdefault_copyright_name {
    setCurrent.dataWrap = {field:field_copyright_name}
    current = 1
    override = "Copyright by me"
    override.if.isFalse.field = field_copyright_name
}


lib.hint_copyright_name = COA
lib.hint_copyright_name.10 < switchdefault_copyright_name
```

**But how to integrate the "first fallback"?**

## EDIT:

I tried:

```
setCurrent.data = {levelfield:-1, field_copyright_name, slide}
```

or

```
setCurrent.data = levelfield:-1, field_copyright_name, slide
```

or

```
setCurrent.dataWrap = {levelfield:-1, field_copyright_name, slide}
```

or

```
setCurrent.dataWrap = levelfield:-1, field_copyright_name, slide
```

but without success - no output.

Comment: can you try something like this in your rootpage: 
lib.hint_copyright_name.10 {
 data = {field:field_copyright_name}:0 // {field:field_copyright_name}:1 // {field:field_copyright_name}:2
}
or with field:
lib.hint_copyright_name.10 {
 field = field_copyright_name:0 // field_copyright_name:1 // field_copyright_name:2
}
Im not sure if this works.

Comment: Suggestion of Rito do not work (because i do not want to limit the levels to 3 in total).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this : http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2006-October/032764.html

It's supposed to make youre slide thing to work.
Just set : Installation > all configuration > addRootLineFields

Didn't tried it, but seems like the solution